# Real robot ur5 is not moving with moveit

Tags: ros2, moveit, motion-planning, moveit-setup-assistant, moveit-commander

I am connected to a UR5 over the network, working on ROS2 humble, on Ubuntu 22.04

- I set up the right host IP on the robot and robot’s IP in the launch file
- I installed the external control urcap.
- I tried with both enable/disable remote control, and with both local/remote control on teach pendant

then i run on one terminal:

```
ros2 launch ur_robot_driver ur_control.launch.py ur_type:=ur5 robot_ip:=192.168.1.102 launch_rviz:=true
```

After that, I run the program on the teach pendant of the robot with the external control (with the correct IP).

On another terminal I run:

```
ros2 launch ur_robot_driver test_scaled_joint_trajectory_controller.launch.py
```

On 3rd terminal i run:

```
ros2 launch ur_moveit_config ur_moveit.launch.py ur_type:=ur5e launch_rviz:=true
```

Rviz starts with the robot at the right position.
I plan and execute a random trajectory. The plan which i plan and execute is visible in rviz
and i get this output in 3rd terminal:

```
Completed trajectory execution with status SUCCEEDED
Solution was found and executed.
Plan and Execute request complete!
```

However the real robot does not move.
There is no error in the terminals.

Any clue what could be the problem here?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I noticed that you have been using `ur5` and `ur5e` interchangeably. It is important to note that these are two distinct robots. Based on my understanding, you are most likely using `ur5e`. Please double-check and ensure that you have `ur_type:=ur5e` in all your commands to avoid any confusion.

Comment: i used ur_type:=ur5 in my all command                                                                                               but i get the same error

Comment: You could also provide the output fron your terminals. Perhaps and info/warning messages couls help.